# Backup and restore of root file system (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, xfs

It seems I will have to move my root FS from XFS v4 to v5 because there seems to be a [move to remove v4 support from Linux kernel](http://tw.spinics.net/lists/linux-xfs/msg41103.html). I can use `tar` to backup and restore files but I am not sure if that is enough to backup and restore my root FS.

I believe I can eventually figure it out but I would rather work with a tried procedure / check list than trying my own ad hoc procedure.

Is there a good checklist / how-to for moving root FS (on Ubuntu 20.04, if it matters)?

Comment: Are you using LVM? If so you could do that with pvmove.

Comment: @eblock I am not using LVM.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article helpful when I was moving a root partition...

https://medium.com/@dominikgacek/how-to-move-linux-root-partition-to-another-drive-quickly-31e54fdc9c19

Use sudo `fdisk -l` to identify the device names of your source and destination drives. Execute `sudo dd if=/dev/sdx1 of=/dev/sdy1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync` to clone the source partition to the destination partition. Use `sudo mkdir /mnt/new` and `sudo mount /dev/sdy1 /mnt/new` to mount the new partition. Since both partitions will have the same UUID, you need to generate a new one using `uuidgen` and apply it with `sudo tune2fs`. Edit `/etc/fstab` to replace the old UUID with the new one. Finally, update the GRUB boot loader.

Comment: I ran out of free Medium articles :(. And link only responses are generally discouraged due to link rot. Do you think you could summarize the article, please? Or include the relevant parts